# Beamer: Make logo from headline overlap into frametitle

Tags: beamer, graphics, boxes, grouping

### Goal

I'm trying to create a `beamer` theme where in the top we have the following layout:

```
________________________________________
|                       |               |
| Author & Insitute     | L O G O       |
|_______________________|_         _____|
|                         \_______/     |
| Frame Title                           |
|_______________________________________|
|                                       |
|  C O N T E N T   H E R E    . . .     |
```

ie. an *overlapping logo*.

### Approaches

I have three approaches but I haven't gotten either to work:

1. Put the **Frame Title** into the **Head Line** as well, then try to achieve the wanted layout using `beamercolorbox` -- but not only did I not achieve the layout, it seems that you cannot also put the **Frame Title** into the **Head Line**.
2. Have the **Head Line** only contain **Authorship Info** and **Logo**, but make the latter somehow "overlap" into the stuff below, without pushing the **Frame Title** down.
3. Make the **Head Line** vertically bigger, containing also the overlapping area, this'd mean that also the background (if existing) of the **Head Line** needed to be colored in two colors, because it actually just took some part of the **Frame Title** area-wise.

The three approaches I've tried to illustrate here:

[image: Approach 1]
**Approach 1**

---

[image: Approach 2]
**Approach 2**

---

[image: Approach 3]
**Approach 3**

---

### MWE / Code

What I've done code-wise so far is:

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{mytheme}

\title{The Title}
\author{S.~Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=0.5cm]{logo}{example-image}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{logo}}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and in my local `TEXMF`: `tex/latex/beamertheme-mytheme/`

`beamerthememytheme.sty`:

```
\mode<presentation>

\useinnertheme{mytheme}
\useoutertheme{mytheme}
\usecolortheme{mytheme}

\mode<all>
```

`beamerouterthememytheme.sty`:

```
\mode<presentation>

% background: transparent    
\setbeamercolor{background}{bg=}
% Grid overlay, to test alignment, 0.028 is given magic value
\setbeamertemplate{background}[grid][step=0.028\pagewidth]

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{mytheme}
{%
    % either make headline contain
    %  1. both logo and frame title (not possible?)
    %  2. only logo, and let it somehow "grow" or "overlap" into the frame title
    %  3. only logo + some vertical space to make it seem like it's overlapping, but this would create more problems, probably.
}

\mode
<all>
```

Can you give me any pointers which of these might be the best approach (or if none, what would be better)? I tried searching and there might really well be a solution to this, but I think I lack the terminology for finding anything useful right now.

Comment: It's always a good idea to provide a minimal working example.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner
I tried to make one but there's nothing "working" I could provide, I'm failing and even getting this layouted roughly the way as described.

Comment: `Working` isn't meant literally: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228. Provide a framework that only includes relevant code.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes, but with not-working I mean, there's nothing to show but the usual boilerplate of `\defbeamertemplate*{headline}`. My question is about not having even an approach to how to solve this.

Comment: No need to fight over this. Your question did not get much attention so far and I wanted to give you an advice.

Comment: @larkey Even if you only have the "usual boilerplate", some ready to compile code would save us from setting up a new document form scratch.

Comment: @larkey Can you also add to your images where which text should be positioned?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes, but I'm afraid I don't know what to add here.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I've tried to address your points and revised the question, it's not much more than boilerplate code though, I'm afraid

Comment: @samcarter I've tried to address your points and revised the question, it's not much more than boilerplate code though, I'm afraid

Answer (score 2):

A bit hacky, but the basic idea is to have the logo and the coloured areas in the background. For the following example I used https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXQjl.png as image.

caveat: frames without frametitle will still have the Gray line

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamerfont{headline}{size=\normalfont}
\setbeamercolor{headline}{bg=white}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,left,wd=.67\paperwidth]{headline}
        \usebeamerfont{headline}%
        \insertshortauthor~\&~\insertshortinstitute 
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=}
\setbeamercolor{framesubtitle}{bg=gray!55!white}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \vspace*{-0.1cm}
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,left,wd=\the\@tempdima]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fteleft\endcsname\fi%
    \strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
   \end{beamercolorbox}
%    {%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip-0.3cm%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.1cm,left,wd=\the\@tempdima]{framesubtitle} 
        {\hspace{0.2cm}\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}        
      \fi
%    }%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
%  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{background}{bg=}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=.17\paperheight]{XXQjl}}

\logo{\includegraphics[width=.2\paperwidth]{example-image}}


\title{The Title}
\author{S.~Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{background}{}
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\framesubtitle{subtitle}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]